# AS3 Error 1046 - trying to pull data from an XML file

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

btn_submit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, xmlLookup);

function xmlLookup(Event:MouseEvent)
{
    var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var xmlData:XML = new XML();
    xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadXML);
    xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("xmldata.xml"));

    function LoadXML(Event:Event):void
    {
        xmlData = new XML(Event.target.data);
        ...
```

I'm receiving this error when trying to test the document

> 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Event.

and it's pointing to this line:

```
function LoadXML(Event:Event):void
```

I've made sure to import flash.events.Event, and in the past I've used this same code without issue - only now I have nested it inside another button click function.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It's working now..

`function LoadXML(Event:Event):void` was using a capital letter for ***input***'s reference name.

*`LoadXML(input:Type)`* = correct.

*`LoadXML(Input:Type)`* = wrong (because `Input` cannot be **C**apital).

I retyped everything and now it's just working.

```
btn_submit.buttonMode = true;
btn_submit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, xmlLookup);

//load XML file
function xmlLookup(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var xmlData:XML = new XML();
    xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadXML);
    xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("xmldata.xml"));

    function LoadXML(e:Event):void
    {
        xmlData = new XML(e.target.data);
        ...
```

Comment: See how even `xmlLookup(event:MouseEvent)` has no capital input name?

Comment: Ah right I see now, I had no idea and stumbled upon that by chance. Thanks for explaining it now, makes much more sense.

Comment: Capital letters don't matter here; change your code to `function LoadXML(Evt1:Event):void` and it will work.  The real culprit is that you can't use a type name as an identifier in your function declaration.